# Is there anyway to increase multiple variables with same value in a single statement

Tags: c#

I wanna increase multiple variables with same value, like this:

```cs
A += 2;
B += 2;
C += 2;
```

But in a single statement.

I've already tried:

```
A += B += C =+ 2;
```

But it's wrong. This stack "2" many times. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such syntax in C# to do that.

You can, of course, put all of the increment operations on a single line:

```cs
A += 2; B += 2; C += 2;
```

But that's not really what you're asking for.

I will point out that, if you find this to be a common pattern in your code — common enough that you feel there ought to be a special syntax in the language to support it — you are probably overlooking an opportunity to define a new type, probably a `struct`, to represent the triplet values you're finding yourself adjusting uniformly on a regular basis.

For example, you might have something like this:

```cs
struct MyStruct
{
    public int A { get; }
    public int B { get; }
    public int C { get; }

    public MyStruct(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }

    public static MyStruct operator +(MyStruct v, int i)
    {
        return new MyStruct(v.A + i, v.B + i, v.C + i);
    }
}
```

which you could then use like this:

```cs
MyStruct v = new MyStruct(1, 2, 3);

v += 2;
// v.A is now 3, v.B is now 4, v.C is now 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is completely nonsensical and has little real world value, but you could use *pointers* and `unsafe`

```
static unsafe void Mutate(int*[] ary, Func<int,int> func)
{
   foreach (var item in ary)
      *item = func(*item);
}
static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
   var a = 0;
   var b = 0;
   var c = 0;

   var ary = new [] { &a, &b,&c};
   Mutate(ary, x => x + 2);

   Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

**Output**

```
2
```

or

```
static unsafe void Mutate(Func<int, int> func, params int*[] array )
{
   foreach (var item in array)
      *item = func(*item);
}

...

Mutate(x => x + 2, &a, &b, &c);
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

or

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static unsafe void Mutate( this int*[] array, Func<int, int> func)
   {
      foreach (var item in array)
         *item = func(*item);
   }
}

...

var list = new  [] { &a, &b,&c};
list.Mutate(x => x + 2);
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Comment: _"This is completely nonsensical"_ -- you said it, not me. :) That said: for small numbers of variables, a not-unsafe `Mutate()` method with `ref` parameters would work just as well. For large numbers of variables, well...those ought to be in an array anyway, and so not-unsafe `Mutate()` method that takes an array as the parameter instead of individual variable references would also work just as well. The above is an interesting exercise, but I'm not sure it's practical. :) (also, all your lambdas have `x += 2`, when `x + 2` would work at least as well)

Comment: @PeterDuniho yeah all good points, this would be failing my code review for sure

Comment: You say that this is "_completely nonsensical_" and I am in a situation where I want to do this, so is my following reason justifiable?
I am storing the sale values form a list of objects to e.g. `salesDay`, `salesWeek` and `salesMonth` and then using those to display a HTML table. 
I think of doing this as I feel it would be easier to read the code when adding the same value to these variables, rather than adding the values of the smaller amount in its logic.
I want to code the best way possible, but I am now wondering if this is bad code practice.

Comment: @Sondre i would probably look at peters example first before doing this. unsafe has its uses, though this is a little overkill